# PyCharm Django test runner can't see django.sites (Runtime Error)

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-sites

When I run `manage.py test` everything is working normally, but if run test with PyCharm Django Tests it gives me following error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 577, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 32, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: order_form.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 312, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/vagrant/project/order_form/tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Order
  File "/home/vagrant/project/order_form/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .pagemodel import *  # nopyflakes
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 83, in <module>
    class Site(models.Model):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 102, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

**Yes, I've enabled** `'django.contrib.sites'` **in INSTALLED_APPS and SITE_ID is set.**

[image: Pycharm Django test configuraion]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're using proper virtualenv?

Comment: do you run `manage.py test` inside of your vagrant box - obviously the pycharm project is configured to use a venv inside of vagrant.

Comment: @dahrens, yes i run `manage.py test` inside Vagrant venv.

Comment: but the working directory which is by default part of the python path is configured outside? Can you specify it from within the vagrant box? ... just an quick idea...

Comment: @dahrens, no result :/

Comment: based on [this post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/03/feature-spotlight-python-remote-development-with-pycharm/) you might want to define the remote vagrant box using `ssh://vagrant@....`

Comment: @dahrens , the same result, I will try to do it with local virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created local virtualenv and install same requirements — tests work fine with it.

Thanks, everybody for comments.